# Display property of overlays

Tags: emacs, overlay

Is it possible to put both a string and an image into an overlay?

So far I know how to put a string into an overlay:

```
(overlay-put ov 'display "...")
```

Or a image:

```
(overlay-put ov 'display '(image :type xbm :file "~/foo.xbm"))
```

But how do I achieve both? The following does not work:

```
(overlay-put ov 'display
             (concat
              "..."
              (propertize " "
                          'display '(image :type xbm :file "~/foo.xbm"))))
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what would you expect the result to look like? An image with the text displayed on top of it?

Comment: Because you could use `(overlay-out ov 'before-string "...")` to add the string before the image

Comment: @picklerick You are right. I didn't consider 'before-string. That's it. Thank you.

Comment: @picklerick Hmm... That's odd. Now the face property `(overlay-put ov 'face '(...))` does not apply on the string in `'before-string`. Instead of that you have to propertize the string itself: `(overlay-put ov 'before-string (propertize "..." 'face '(...)))`. Well, not a big issue.

Comment: yea, I believe that is because font-lock doesn't operate on overlays, but I may be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken an overlay property can have only one value, and of course you cannot have multiple properties with the same name.